# @XmlAccessorType that applied to nested classes

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to convert a java class object to xml using `javax.xml.bind` library.

This class has nested classes on which I need to apply class level `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)` annotation. However, I am not allowed to change the source code of the nested classes.

For example, I need to convert class `Abc` to `xml`:

```
Public class Abc {
    private A a; // class A is defined later
    private String b;
    // getters and setters
}

public class A {
    private String s;
    //getters and setters
}
```

I wish to apply `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)` annotation to class A, but am not allowed to change its source code. Also, class A resides in a different package.

Is there a way to specify some kind of global setting of `XmlAccessorType` which will apply to to class Abc as well as its nested classes (such as A)?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend from class `A` and use that child class in your `Abc` class.

```
Public class Abc {
    private B b; // class A is defined later
    private String b;
    // getters and setters
}

public class A {
    private String s;
    //getters and setters
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class B extends A {
  ...
}
```